# defined "jdbc.properties" for mybatis, but still need add spring.datasource in application.properties?

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm new to spring boot and mybatis. I generated my spring boot mybatis project with spring initilizer.
Here's my config:

***application.properties***

```
mybatis.config-location=classpath:mybatis/mybatis-config.xml
mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath:mybatis/mappers/*.xml
```

***mybatis-config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <properties resource="mybatis/jdbc.properties"></properties>

    <settings>
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
    </settings>

    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="com.mns.ssm.typehandlers.BooleanTypeHandler"></typeHandler>
    </typeHandlers>

    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"></transactionManager>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"/>
                <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
                <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
                <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
</configuration>
```

***jdbc.properties***

```
jdbc.driverClass=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=root
```

I think it's enough, but when I run the application, it show errors

```
SsmApplicationTests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:798
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:656
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                    Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException at DataSourceProperties.java:235
```

But when I add the config to application.properties.  it works fine.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

I'm really confused,  anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class should be excluded,like this :
[image]